# Write-Host 2x select statements with different values

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a script that gets information about a user, including some info about their computer.  The problem I am facing is that I am unable to write two different select statements (both writing to host) in the script.  Regardless of how far apart they are separated the script treats them as one long running select statement and because the fields don't exist on the second statement it prints nothing.  Which results in nothing at all being printed.  see example:

```
Get-ADUser "jDoe" | select Surname, OfficePhone
Get-ADComputer "jDoe-01" | select OperatingSystem,DNSHostName
Pause
```

Run code:

```
Surname      OfficePhone
-------      -----------
John Doe     +123456789

Press any key to continue...
```

Does anyone know of a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the output displayed on screen before processing the next command pipe it into Format-Table:

`Get-ADUser "jDoe" | select Surname, OfficePhone | ft
Get-ADComputer "jDoe-01" | select OperatingSystem,DNSHostName | ft`

Comment: You are amazing!  I thought the format-table command would change the formatting to a table, not leave the formatting as-is.  I guess not....lol

Answer (score 1):

The properties you're asking for aren't included in the default output of 'Get-ADComputer'.  Update with this:

```
Get-ADComputer "jDoe-01" -Properties OperatingSystem,DNSHostName | select OperatingSystem,DNSHostName
```